# How can I set up a ruler at a specific column?

Tags: alignment, colorcolumn

When coding in different languages, I tend to need to restrict my lines to a specific length (usually 79 or 80 characters).

I've seen this done in other editors through the use of a ruler (solid line displayed at the column) or by changing the color of the text to indicate that it has gone over.

How can I have Vim indicate to me when I am approaching or going over 79 characters in a single line?

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You can display a ruler at a specific line using the `:set colorcolumn` (`:set cc` for short) option which is only available in Vim 7.3 or later.

```
set colorcolumn=80
```

This will set the background color of that column to red, giving you a visual ruler to work from.

[image: Picture of default colorcolumn set to 80]

If you want to use a different color other than red (which really stands out), you can change the color by setting the `highlight` for `ColorColumn`.

```
highlight ColorColumn ctermbg=0 guibg=lightgrey
```

[image: Customized color for the column]

You can set the color for terminal versions of Vim using the `cterm` argument and GUI versions of Vim using the `guibg` argument. The `0` is the value of the ASCII escape code for black, which is grey when brightened (which it is, by default). The value `lightgrey` is used for GUI versions of Vim, like gVim, to change the background color to a light grey.

Comment: You can even have multiple comma-separated colorcolumns!

Comment: Combine that with join & range, and you can have a bunch of columns colored with very little code. My .vimrc has: `execute "set colorcolumn=" . join(range(81,335), ',')`

Comment: Is there a way to set this `colorcolumn` only for specific file types, say Fortran 77 files?

Comment: In addition to **ctermbg** to change the background color, one can also set **ctermfg** to also change the foreground color for that column.

Comment: @zyy You'd want to look into the use of autocmd with FileType in your vimrc. I do this with ReStructuredText files with this in my vimrc. (I have the riv plugin setup to identify the file type.) `autocmd FileType rst    set colorcolumn=100`

Answer (score 28):

As an addendum to Kevin's answer, you can have multiple colorcolumns. When I code, I sometimes have a "soft" limit at 80 columns and a "hard" limit at 120 columns. So I want a line at 80, and then every column after 120 to be colored.

I do this with

```
let &colorcolumn="80,".join(range(120,999),",")
```

Of course, this can be easily modified to other preferences.

Answer (score 16):

Vim 7.3 brings the `colorcolumn` option, as detailed very well in other answers.

However, if you don't have version 7.3 for whatever reason, you can still achieve a visual indication that you are exceeding a particular column count using vim's `match` functionality (see `:help match` for details).

Essentially, the match commands allow you to create persistent highlights for text matching a given regular expression. `:match ColorColumn "\%80v."` will highlight text in column 80 with the "ColorColumn" group. You can of course substitute any highlight group, and any column value. If you want a strong visual indication, the expression `"\%>79v.\+"` will highlight column 80 and beyond.

(`\%80v` means "match in virtual column 80," and `\%>79v` means "match *after* virtual column 79; see `:help /\%c` for more.)

This approach will only highlight when there are actual characters present in the specified columns, however, which makes it visually less consistent than `colorcolumn`.

Comment: Personally I find the less consistent approach of `match`es better, as it highlights only those lines where I am exceeding the 80-column limit, rather than showing a (to me) intrusive big red line on the right of the screen. Hence in my vimrc for Python I use `call matchadd('ColorColumn', '\(\%80v\|\%100v\)')` (80 and 100 being the suggested lengths in PEP 8)

Answer (score 3):

I mostly do coding in vim (version 7.4) and I have added the below two lines in my .vimrc to maintain a "colorcolumn" for 100 character length.

```
:set colorcolumn=100                                                                                
:hi ColorColumn ctermbg=lightcyan guibg=blue
```

My environment is a color-xterm so I usually populate the "ctermbg" argument.

For someone curious, to find the available colour names in your vim, open vim and run the below command. It will show you a list of colour names that can be used as argument values.

```
:so $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/colortest.vim
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to all the colorcolumn answers, my mappings to make `\ln` set the highlight line to the current cursor position, and `\nl` to unset.

```
function! VerticalLineHere(doeet)
    if a:doeet
        let &colorcolumn=col('.')
    else
        let &colorcolumn=0
    endif
endfunction
nnoremap <leader>line :call VerticalLineHere(1)<cr>
nnoremap <leader>ln :call VerticalLineHere(1)<cr>
nnoremap <leader>noline :call VerticalLineHere(0)<cr>
nnoremap <leader>nl :call VerticalLineHere(0)<cr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `colorcolumn` accepts a comma-separated list of arguments, so in my case I have the following setting in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set colorcolumn=72,80,120
hi ColorColumn ctermbg=lightgrey guibg=lightgrey
```

See also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50317494
- https://www.baeldung.com/linux/vim-ruler-on-specific-column

Comment: It also accepts special values that draw columns relative to textwidth, IIRC